# Web site web.config error?

Tags: iis

I don't know what this error means:

> it is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Can someone tell me what this error means and how to fix it?

EDIT: Also, when I click on the error, it brings me to this line of code in the web.config: `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Comment: I bet you are placing a web app with a web.config file in a folder configured as a site in IIS that has no associated app pool (or not running in integrated mode). You can convert the site to an application in IIS and that should fix it up.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is telling you, you need to mark your virtual directory / website as an Application in IIS Manager.

Comment: Can you show me how to fix it? I have just started doing websites.

Comment: There is one problem. I can't open IIS Manager because I am not a Administrator, I am only a 12-year-old boy messing around with web sites. =-(

Comment: Then you can't do this.  Gotta be an admin.

Comment: You can use IIS Express.

Comment: Hey guys, I figured out how to do it, but thanks anyway for trying to help me! =-D